# How to URLEncode within aura:component

Tags: aura

With an VisualForce page, we just call URLEncode.  Took 5 minutes for me to figure that out.

How to we do the equivalent inside an aura:component, with markup like this:

`<iframe src="{!'https://example.com/Encode This'}" ..... />`

This obviously does not work:
`<iframe src="{!URLENCODE('https://example.com/Encode This')}" ..... />`

I have spent 2 hours googling and trying different things to no avail.  This seems unreasonably hard.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no expression that allows you to do this. If you need encoding, do so in your controller. For example:

```
<aura:attribute name="iframeSrc" type="String" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<iframe src="{!v.iframeSrc}"></iframe>
```

...

```
doInit: function(component, event, handler) {
  component.set("v.iframeSrc", encodeURI("https://www.example.com/Encode This"));
}
```

Otherwise, you'd want to manually encode the URL:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/Encode%20This" ..... />
```

For a full list of functions you can actually use, see [Expressions Function Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm).

You'll notice it is significantly slimmer than the Visualforce formulas that you can use; most anything you'd expect to do in markup in Visualforce is done by the controller in Lightning.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  You have certainly set me on the right path and I have got it working.  I ended up changing to use the render event (rather than init) as some data I needed wasn't available yet in init - but it is working perfectly now.

Very much appreciate your response!